# Globally enable ssh-dss on openssh 7.0

Tags: ssh, openssh

I know I can add the following entry:

`PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss`

to `~/.ssh/config` as described [here](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html)
but I need to do so for each entry. I want to enable it globally.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable it for all connections you personally make (rather than for all users on the system), just put it in your `~/.ssh/config` one time:

```
Host *
    PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

This will apply to all hosts unless overridden with a different `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` setting in a subsequent specific `Host` clause.  From [`man ssh_config`](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> A single ‘*’ as a pattern can be used to provide global defaults for all hosts.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this line in

```
/etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

This will make it valid for every user on this server